# Oracle - exchange partitions with a table

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I try to create a table2 on Oracle 11g.2.0.3 with:

```
CREATE table2 
LOGGING TABLESPACE TS_table1_2014 PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 STORAGE ( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT ) NOCOMPRESS
as (select * from table1 where date_text <= '2015-12-31');
```

and I have received error below when I try to exchange this table2 with a partitioned table3:

```
alter table table3 exchange partition partition_name WITH TABLE table2;

    Error report -
    SQL Error: ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
    14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
    *Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
               ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
    *Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns
               with the same type and size.
```

I have test diferences with query below:

```
Select a.COLUMN_NAME 
  , a.DATA_TYPE, b.DATA_TYPE 
  , a.data_length, b.data_length 
  , a.data_precision, b.data_precision 
  , a.data_scale, b.data_scale 
  , a.nullable, b.nullable 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a 
full outer join ALL_TAB_COLUMNS b on a.column_name=b.column_name 
 and b.owner=user and b.table_name='&table2' 
 where  a.owner=user and a.table_name='&table1'   
 and ( 
    nvl(a.data_type,'#')!=nvl(b.data_type,'#') 
    or nvl(a.data_length,-1)!=nvl(b.data_length,-1) 
    or nvl(a.data_precision,-100)!=nvl(b.data_precision,-100) 
    or nvl(a.data_scale,-100)!=nvl(b.data_scale,-100) 
    or nvl(a.nullable,'#')!=nvl(b.nullable,'#') 
   ) 
;
```

Some differences resulted are in a column size. This syntax "create as select" didn't keep order and size for new table created.

How can I create table2 **as select** from table1 with force keep same size columns as primary table1 source?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your DDL for table1 as well as for table3?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ce5xbAS0

Comment: On another datase with similar tables, all columns size and order are ok created with simple syntax "create as select".  I suspect different rights on user allocated.

Comment: You should be doing your partitions like this: VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'))

Comment: also need DDL or structure for table1

Comment: This is creation of table1: https://pastebin.com/3KJwJwc9

Comment: Column col3 is named date_text, from first pastebin link (for table3).

Comment: so table1 has date_text and table3 has col3?

Comment: table3 has date_text instead of col3

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any differences in your DDL.  What I suggest is to use the same DDL to create table2, then do:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid insert into. I use 'create table as select' for execution speed.

Comment: You can insert together with FETCH BULK and FORALL.  Also, we were discussing syntax errors, not performance right :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dbms_metadata package or query number of data dictionary views like all_tab_columns and etc to get metadata about existing table so you can construct correct sql for swap-table (used in exchange partition operation). CTAS does not transfer DEFAULT values for example and constraints except NOT NULL checks.
The best practice is to create/re-create/modify this table simultaneously with partitioned table.